# Compare several dataframe columns to list

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this (the columns are not side by side):

```
 Num A Num B Num C Marked
0  213   314   512
1  612   516   713
2  613   678   125
3  163   813   312
```

And a list like  `list = [612,813,512,713]`

I now want to compare, if a value from the list is present in the dataframe, and mark it with 1, else with 0, so that the output is:

```
 Num A Num B Num C Marked
0  213   314   512      1
1  612   516   713      1
2  613   678   125      0
3  163   813   312      1
```

I only found out how to do this with a single column:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "path"
wb = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = wb.parse("Sheet1")

list = [612,813,512,713]

df['Marked'] = df.Num_A.isin.(list).astype(int)
```

How can you make this to consider all columns?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: don't use "list" as a vairable name, this is already used by native python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.isin` method to check if numbers in `lst` exist in `df` along columns and then convert it to integer value:

```
df['Marked'] = np.isin(df.values,lst).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a 2. df, use the isin there, add prefix to columns of second dataframe, then join them together:

```
lst = [612,813,512,713]

df.join(df.isin(lst).add_prefix('Marked_'))
```